Need to create support of lineage 19.1 for gta4l (LTE)
I was creating a custom ROM build for gta4l for lineage19.1. I have configured vendor, system and device files properly from many sources and the build has started. Now the issue is it's syncing for the same os from github using the .repo file. Problem is since LineageOS 19.1 doesn't support gta4l so it can't checkout to the proper repo and branch. Is there any way I can. It's done by the files in .repo/manifest_xml.py etc. Following is the error log.
Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/gta4l
Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/gta4l-common
Looking for dependencies in hardware/samsung
hardware/samsung has no additional dependencies.
Looking for dependencies in kernel/samsung/sm6115
kernel/samsung/sm6115 has no additional dependencies.

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=12
LINEAGE_VERSION=19.1-20240629-UNOFFICIAL-gta4l
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_gta4l
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.5.0-41-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.4-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=SQ3A.220705.004
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=vendor/samsung/gta4l vendor/samsung/gta4l-common device/samsung/gta4l-common hardware/samsung hardware/qcom-caf/sm8250 vendor/qcom/opensource/commonsys/display vendor/qcom/opensource/commonsys-intf/display vendor/qcom/opensource/display vendor/qcom/opensource/data-ipa-cfg-mgr vendor/qcom/opensource/dataservices packages/apps/Bluetooth
============================================
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:199: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:200: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=12
LINEAGE_VERSION=19.1-20240629-UNOFFICIAL-gta4l
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_gta4l
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.5.0-41-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.4-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=SQ3A.220705.004
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=vendor/samsung/gta4l vendor/samsung/gta4l-common device/samsung/gta4l-common hardware/samsung hardware/qcom-caf/sm8250 vendor/qcom/opensource/commonsys/display vendo
r/qcom/opensource/commonsys-intf/display vendor/qcom/opensource/display vendor/qcom/opensource/data-ipa-cfg-mgr vendor/qcom/opensource/dataservices packages/apps/Bluetooth
============================================
[ 0% 533/113428] build out/target/product/gta4l/obj/ETC/build-manifest_intermediates/build-manifest.xml
FAILED: out/target/product/gta4l/obj/ETC/build-manifest_intermediates/build-manifest.xml
/bin/bash -c "(mkdir -p out/target/product/gta4l/obj/ETC/build-manifest_intermediates/ ) && (python3 .repo/repo/repo manifest -o - -r | grep -Ev \"proprietary_\" > out/target/product/gta4l/o
bj/ETC/build-manifest_intermediates/build-manifest.xml )"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/main.py", line 874, in <module>
_Main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/main.py", line 850, in _Main
result = repo._Run(name, gopts, argv) or 0
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/main.py", line 294, in _Run
result = run()
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/main.py", line 275, in <lambda>
lambda: self._RunLong(name, gopts, argv, git_trace2_event_log) or 0
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/main.py", line 442, in _RunLong
execute_command()
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/main.py", line 408, in execute_command
execute_command_helper()
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/main.py", line 374, in execute_command_helper
result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/subcmds/manifest.py", line 179, in Execute
self._Output(opt)
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/subcmds/manifest.py", line 157, in _Output
manifest.Save(
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 854, in Save
doc = self.ToXml(**kwargs)
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 764, in ToXml
output_projects(None, root, list(sorted(projects)))
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 659, in output_projects
output_project(parent, parent_node, project)
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 689, in output_project
value = p.work_git.rev_parse(HEAD + "^0")
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/project.py", line 3763, in runner
p.Wait()
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/git_command.py", line 564, in Wait
self.VerifyCommand()
File "/media/astar/CodeDecoders/android/lineage18/.repo/repo/git_command.py", line 554, in VerifyCommand
raise GitCommandError(
git_command.GitCommandError: GitCommandError: 'rev-parse HEAD^0' on LineageOS/android_device_samsung_gta4l failed
stderr: fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /media/astar)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

suggestion: Are you running this repo command outside of a repo workspace?
[ 0% 550/113428] //bionic/libc:common_libc versioner preprocess include
warning: attempted to generate guard with empty availability: obsoleted = 21
warning: attempted to generate guard with empty availability: obsoleted = 23
20:35:10 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (27 seconds) ####

